# How to solve for Hyperbola in python

Tags: python-3.x, scipy-optimize

I am trying to solve the hyperbolic equation in the following way to find x and y. I wanted to know if it made sense to use the same equation twice in fsolve to find first x and then y. My code is as follows:

```
from scipy.optimize import * 
from numpy import *
import math

a = 1/(a_6**2)
b = 1/(b_6**2)

def function_hyper(loc):
     x = loc[0]
     y = loc[1]
            
     F = empty((2))
     F[0] = a*pow(x, 2) - b*pow(y, 2) - 1
     F[1] = a*pow(x, 2) - b*pow(y, 2) - 1
     return F1
loc_Guess = np.array([0.0141, 0.107])
location = fsolve(function_hyper, loc_Guess)
```

Here, `a_6` and `b_6` are variables calculated from previous steps. `a` and `b` are co-efficients for solving hyperbolic equation of `x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 = 1`. This is the equation I have written in `F[0]` and `F[1]`. `empty` is to define F before using it. So after having values for `F`, empty gets replaced. `pow` is to define a power of 2 for squaring x and y.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's not clear what `a1_6` and `b1_6` are. The same holds for the `empty` and `pow` methods if you don't provide all your imports.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, fsolve is just a Wrapper around MINPACK's [hybrd](https://www.math.utah.edu/software/minpack/minpack/hybrd.html) routine:

> The purpose of HYBRD is to find a zero of a system of N non-linear functions in N variables by a modification of the Powell hybrid method. The user must provide a subroutine which calculates the functions. The Jacobian is then calculated by a forward-difference approximation.

Consequently, you need N equations to find the root of a function in N variables. Hence, in case one wants to find the root of a function `f: R^N -> R` one could either solve the system of N equations `(f(x), ..., f(x)) = (0, ..., 0)`  (like you did) or simply `(f(x), 0, ..., 0) = (0, ..., 0)`. The latter looks like this in code:

```py
import numpy as np

a = 1/(a_6**2)
b = 1/(b_6**2)

def function_hyper(loc):
     x, y = loc[0], loc[1]      
     F = np.zeros(2)
     F[0] = a * x**2 - b * y**2 - 1
     return F
```